Showing CSV Data in HTML but not as a table
I am trying to show data from csv file into html using papa parse and js. I don't want to show as a table, instead I want to show as a card using html and css styling but js can't parse the csv. When I look at the console log, I don't know why the results show html file when I clearly put the path as csv file.
My csv File:
image_path,name,description,price
/KMS/web-files/pop1.png,Product 1,This is the first product,10.99
/KMS/web-files/pop2.png,Product 2,This is the second product,12.49
/KMS/web-files/pop3.png,Product 3,This is the third product,8.99

My code:
    <div class="row sectionBlockLayout text-start" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: 0px; min-height: auto; padding: 8px; align-items: center; width: 1166px; right: 0;">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>CSV Data Display</title>
      <style>
          .card {
              border: 1px solid #ccc;
              padding: 16px;
              margin: 8px;
              text-align: center;
          }
          .card img {
              max-width: 100px;
              height: auto;
          }
          .price {
              color: green;
              font-weight: bold;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div id="cards-container"></div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      fetch('./data.csv')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
          console.log('Raw CSV Data:', data);  // Log the raw CSV data to see if it was fetched correctly
          Papa.parse(data, {
            header: true,
            complete: function(results) {
              console.log('Parsed CSV Data:', results.data);  // Log the parsed data to see how it looks
              const container = document.getElementById('cards-container');
              results.data.forEach(row => {
                console.log('Row:', row);  // Log each row to see the structure
  
                const card = document.createElement('div');
                card.className = 'card';
                
                const img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = row.image_path || 'default_image.jpg'; // Use a default image if image_path is missing
                img.onerror = () => img.src = 'default_image.jpg';  // Fallback in case of broken image link
                card.appendChild(img);
                
                const name = document.createElement('h3');
                name.textContent = row.name || 'No Name'; // Handle missing name
                card.appendChild(name);
                
                const description = document.createElement('p');
                description.textContent = row.description || 'No Description'; // Handle missing description
                card.appendChild(description);
                
                const price = document.createElement('p');
                price.className = 'price';
                price.textContent = `$${row.price || '0.00'}`; // Handle missing price
                card.appendChild(price);
                
                container.appendChild(card);
              });
            },
            error: function(error){
              console.error('Parsing error: ', error.message);
            }
          });
        })
          .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching CSV:', error));  // Log any errors that occur during the fetch
      });
  </script>
  
  </body>
  

</div>

This is my output


what is the output of console.log('Row:', row);

Row:
Object
""
:
""
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
constructor
:
ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
ƒ toLocaleString()
toString
:
ƒ toString()
valueOf
:
ƒ valueOf()
defineGetter
:
ƒ defineGetter()
defineSetter
:
ƒ defineSetter()
lookupGetter
:
ƒ lookupGetter()
lookupSetter
:
ƒ lookupSetter()
proto
:
(...)
get proto
:
ƒ proto()
set proto
:
ƒ proto()

so, it doesn't have any of the properties you think it does ... like .image_path or .name or .description or .price ... there's your problem
